# Flutter/dart how to read qr code from static image

Tags: dart, flutter

There are some good plugins such as **barcode_scaner** can read QR code from the camera. After tons of searching, I still can't find a good solution or any plugin to decode content from a static image saved on the phone which contains a QR code. Could anyone help?